# Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from a use of ‘print’

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I have the following data structure, and I am trying to write a printer for it:

```
data CTypeF a 
    = CVarF Int 
    | CArrF a a
    | CIntF
    | CBoolF
    deriving (Eq, Data, Show, Functor, Foldable, Traversable)
```

The following gives me an error:

```
my_test = do
    let c0 = CIntF
    (print CIntF)
```

This is the error message:

```
• Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from a use of ‘print’
      prevents the constraint ‘(Show a0)’ from being solved.
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘a0’ should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance Show Constr -- Defined in ‘Data.Data’
        instance Show ConstrRep -- Defined in ‘Data.Data’
        instance Show DataRep -- Defined in ‘Data.Data’
        ...plus 40 others
        ...plus 166 instances involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
• In a stmt of a 'do' block: (print CIntF)
          In the expression:
            do let c0 = CIntF
               (print CIntF)
```

I saw the following question [Ambiguous type variable ‘b1’ arising from a use of ‘print’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54865167/ambiguous-type-variable-b1-arising-from-a-use-of-print)

and modified my code to do `(print CIntF :: CTypeF)` but I get:

```
• Expecting one more argument to ‘CTypeF’
      Expected a type, but ‘CTypeF’ has kind ‘* -> *’
```

I am a bit lost on what the issue is. Could someone point out what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the error message says, `CTypeF` takes an argument. `CTypeF` is not a type, but e.g. `CTypeF ()` or `CTypeF Int` or `CTypeF [(String, Double)]` are.

The situation is analogous to `print Nothing` and attempting to fix it by adding `(Nothing :: Maybe)`. You need to specify `Maybe ()` or `Maybe Int` or ...

Try

```
my_test = do
    let c0 = CIntF :: CTypeF ()
    print c0
```

Comment: Is there anyway I could turn this into a printer though? For example something of the form "instance Show CTypeF..". The issue again is I am not sure what to pass as an argument. It should be of the form instance Show CTypeF a where...

Comment: @Lana You already have that instance, from `deriving (... Show ... )`. I don't understand your comment.

Comment: I guess I should say what I was really trying to get to here. I was trying to print an instance of Subst, from this library: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/compdata-0.1/docs/Data-Comp-Variables.html#t:HasVars. This gave me "No instance for (Show (Cxt NoHole CTypeF ()))" So I assumed it was something with the CTypeF printer.

Comment: I'll go ahead and make a different question for that though, since the issue does not seem to be about CTypeF. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that, as Haskell sees it, you havent told it what the `a` in `CTypeF a` is, at least not enough to print it. You might try `print (CIntF :: CTypeF ())`.